# Close Review path, can the questions be presented side-by-side a-la edit reviews?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, review

In the /review/close path, can the questions be presented side-by-side a-la edit reviews?

I don't know how much more needs to be added to this for context, as any mod can open it.

Right now when I open the tool for something with a VtC:Dupe there is a set of tabs. I would like to be able to open the question on the left, and the proposed dupe(s) on the right, so I can look at them side-by-side. I feel like the basic concept of the page exists with proposed edits.

Comment: Of course, it should still have either tabs or some menu to switch through all the duplicates if there are more than one.

Comment: Well I thought that was evident by putting the "dupe(s)" on the right, but yes. That's what I intend.